# HP DL580 Gen8 - not booting after CPU upgrade

Tags: hp, boot, central-processing-unit, upgrade

We bought several used DL580 Gen8 recently. One of them (let's call it type A) had four E7-4830v2 installed and the other (let's call it type B) had  four E7-4880v2 installed. Everything worked fine and we decided to upgrade the CPUs in the type A server. And so we ordered 4 used E7-4890V2 CPUs.

I got to know that it is a good practice to upgrade CPUs gradually because there is a possibility the HP system board could die if 155w TDP CPUs were installed right after ~100w TDP CPUs. So I removed the 4830s from server A and swapped them with 4880s first. Everything went fine and server A would boot and work OK with those CPUs.

Then I updated the BIOS and swapped 4880s with 4890s.

After I installed the new CPUs into server A it doesn't boot. After I press the power button it starts fans for 1-2 secs and then powers off without showing anything on the screen. Internal led is blinking code 80/00. External health led is blinking red at 4Hz (power failure according to HP user manual). I tried to boot it with only 1 or 2 new CPUs and it boots and works perfectly. When I try to boot it with 3 or 4 CPUs or with 2 CPUs installed into sockets #3 or #4 the things I described above start to happen.

I tried to start server B with new CPUs and had no success as well. It doesn't die instantly but tries to do the POST. System initialization progress reaches 6% and then it reboots constantly.

I saw a similar topic about DL580 G7 and they came to a conclusion that the system board revision was the case.

Any thoughts on this? Do we have any chances to start those servers with four 4890s?

Answer (score 1):

Who knows?

Run through the normal troubleshooting steps. For instance, do you know if the used CPUs you purchased are actually known-good?

Step one would be to revert to a working set of CPUs in the affected system. Ensure it can POST.

Step two would be some combination of testing the E7-4890V2 CPUs from one of the other servers in the affected system.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED.

The issue was caused by bent pins in sockets #3 and #4. Got POST after fixing those pins.